# How to count appearances of a value until it changes to another one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe called `df`. In this dataframe, I got one variable called `value`. I want to add a variable to count appearances of a same value until it changes to another one. Let's call this new variable `count`.

My dataframe looks like that:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ar = np.array([[1], [1], [2],[2], [3], [3], [1], [1], [2], [2]])
df = pd.DataFrame(ar,  columns = ['Value'])

print(df)

   Value
0      1
1      1
2      2
3      2
4      3
5      3
6      1
7      1
8      2
9      2
```

I tried this code:

```py
df['count'] = df.groupby('Value').cumcount() + 1
```

Which returns:

```py
print(df)
   Value  count
0      1      1
1      1      2
2      2      1
3      2      2
4      3      1
5      3      2
6      1      3
7      1      4
8      2      3
9      2      4
```

I expect something like this:

```py
print(df)
   Value  count
0      1      1
1      1      2
2      2      1
3      2      2
4      3      1
5      3      2
6      1      1
7      1      2
8      2      1
9      2      2
```

Is there a way to get that output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, use:

```
df=df.assign(count=df.groupby(df.Value.ne(df.Value.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1))
```

---

```
   Value  count
0      1      1
1      1      2
2      2      1
3      2      2
4      3      1
5      3      2
6      1      1
7      1      2
8      2      1
9      2      2
```

Where:

```
print(df.Value.ne(df.Value.shift()))
```

---

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
7    False
8     True
9    False
Name: Value, dtype: bool
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Though @anky_91 answer is perfect,a naive solution can be to create a function `count_upto` without using the methods discussed in his answer.

```py
def count_upto(series):
  count = np.ones(len(series),np.int32)
  for i in range(1,len(series)):
    word=series[i]
    if word == series[i-1]:
      count[i] = count[i-1] +1
  return count

df['count']=count_upto(df.Value.values)
```

```
print(df)
>>>
  Value c
0   1   1
1   1   2
2   1   3
3   2   1
4   3   1
5   3   2
6   1   1
7   1   2
8   2   1
9   2   2
```